# How to get the latest text file based on timestamp from a directory

Tags: shell

I am having a directory as

```
/var/tmp/kick
```

Where it has text files as

```
CCD_FILE_120920150300033.txt
CCD_FILE_121020150300035.txt
```

How to get the latest file based on timestamp and copy the old file into another directory and remove it from present directory which means it 
would extract `CCD_FILE_121020150300035` from `/var/tmp/kick` and make a copy of `CCD_FILE_121020150300033` in `/var/tmp/Vgh` and remove this text file from `/var/tmp/kick`

I am using ksh shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
targetfile="$(ls /var/tmp/kick/CCD_FILE_*.txt | sort -r | tail -n1)"
if [[ -f "${targetfile}" ]]; then
    mv ${targerfile} /var/tmp/Vgh/
fi
```

Comment: What will happen if there is one text file present in /var/tmp/kick and that is the latest time stamp and no previous files are their @DopeGhoti

Comment: If there is at least one matching file, the oldest based on the timestamp in the filename will be moved.  If there is exactly one match, then `/var/tmp/kick` will be left devoid of matching files.